# Recargar pagina desde un href en un <a>

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4

Buenas trabajando hoy se me presento un problema tengo un  con un href que tiene un target="_blank", necesito que cuando le de click aparte de abrir el enlace la pagina se recargue una ves intente con un onclick pero cuando uso el href se deshabilita:

```
             <td>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url().'/obtenerNombregarantia/'.$row['id_inv'] ?>" target= "_blank" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style='background: red; border-color: red;'>Garantia</a>
              <br><br>
              <a  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                  Imp. Grt
              </a>
            </td>
```

Este es parte del codigho ahi esta el href intente con onclick pero ya no manda el otro enlace. Alguna idea o sugerencia seria de mucha ayuda y les agradeceria.
Gracias

Comment: No es así, un onclick se ejecuta antes del href y a menos que canceles la propagación de eventos se ejecutarán ambos. Te recomiendo siempre agregar el código que no funciona en tus preguntas ya que el que agregaste no aparece el onclick, tambien te recomiendo que quites todo el código innecesario como el botón y las clases que no aportan nada al problema

Answer (score 1):

Gracias ya pude solucionarlo subo el codigo:

```
<?php $var= base_url().'/obtenerNombregarantia/'.$row['id_inv']; ?>
            <td>
              <a onclick="relo('<?php echo $var; ?>')" target= "_blank" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style='background: red; border-color: red;'>Garantia</a>
              <br><br>
              <a  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                  Imp. Grt
              </a>
            </td>
```

Aca el script:

```
<script>
  function relo(url){
    console.log("re");
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
    setInterval("location.reload()",5000);
  }   
</script>
```

De esta manera despues de darle click al boton para exportar el pdf 5 segundos despues la pagina se actualiza automaticamente.
Gracias espero les sirva.